# Adamantite Armor vs Palladium Armor

Tags: terraria

I have heard that Palladium Armor is really good for healing. I have Adamantite Armor. Should I change to Palladium? I am currently a melee character.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the paladium armor gives you a 'Rapid Healing buff for 5 seconds when you hit an enemy'.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Palladium_armor

I would switch if you have the ore for it. Otherwise, I would just continue to collect items for the next armor tier.